# How to get/know a message that is processing in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I need to know if it's possible to know or get a message from RabbitMQ (consumers) which is processing (maybe if it's taking long time). But, I don't want to stop the service.  I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Not clear enough for me :) What do you mean by rmq processing message? I mean talking about what the rmq broker does, or the consumers?

Comment: Thanks , indeed i mean the consumers .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean if RabbitMQ provides any build-in notification or tracking about whether a specific message is being processed or not. The answer is No. But you should easily be able to implement one by your own. For instance, when begin to process a message in the consumer, the consumer could send a notification message to a notification queue.